# Phabricator Installation Error with PHP 7.0

Tags: php, mysql, phabricator

I am installing Phabricator on Ubuntu 16.04.

I have PHP 7.0.8-3 installed.

I am at the Setup section at https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuration_guide/

When I go to my site I am getting the error

> 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I tried to run the command

```
 phabricator/ $ ./bin/storage upgrade --user <user> --password <password>
```

But I just get the following error:

> [2016-07-07 17:15:54] EXCEPTION: (Error) Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() at [/src/aphront/storage/connection/mysql/AphrontMySQLDatabaseConnection.php:12]
> arcanist(head=master, ref.master=4d4d16f25985), phabricator(head=master, ref.master=ef13b0e52b46), phutil(head=master, ref.master=32c56dc20b39)
> #0 AphrontMySQLDatabaseConnection::escapeBinaryString(string) called at [/src/aphront/storage/connection/mysql/AphrontMySQLDatabaseConnection.php:8]
> #1 AphrontMySQLDatabaseConnection::escapeUTF8String(string) called at [/src/xsprintf/qsprintf.php:178]
> #2 xsprintf_query(AphrontMySQLDatabaseConnection, string, integer, string, integer) called at [/src/xsprintf/xsprintf.php:70]
> #3 xsprintf(string, AphrontMySQLDatabaseConnection, array) called at [/src/xsprintf/qsprintf.php:64]
> #4 qsprintf(AphrontMySQLDatabaseConnection, string, string, string, string) called at [/src/xsprintf/queryfx.php:5]
> #5 queryfx(AphrontMySQLDatabaseConnection, string, string, string, string) called at [/src/xsprintf/queryfx.php:11]
> #6 queryfx_all(AphrontMySQLDatabaseConnection, string, string, string, string) called at [/src/aphront/storage/connection/AphrontDatabaseConnection.php:26]
> #7 AphrontDatabaseConnection::queryData(string, string, string, string) called at [/src/infrastructure/storage/lisk/LiskDAO.php:535]
> #8 LiskDAO::loadRawDataWhere(string, string) called at [/src/infrastructure/storage/lisk/LiskDAO.php:476]
> #9 LiskDAO::loadAllWhere(string, string) called at [/src/infrastructure/env/PhabricatorConfigDatabaseSource.php:18]
> #10 PhabricatorConfigDatabaseSource::loadConfig(string) called at [/src/infrastructure/env/PhabricatorConfigDatabaseSource.php:7]
> #11 PhabricatorConfigDatabaseSource::__construct(string) called at [/src/infrastructure/env/PhabricatorEnv.php:232]
> #12 PhabricatorEnv::buildConfigurationSourceStack() called at [/src/infrastructure/env/PhabricatorEnv.php:95]
> #13 PhabricatorEnv::initializeCommonEnvironment() called at [/src/infrastructure/env/PhabricatorEnv.php:75]
> #14 PhabricatorEnv::initializeScriptEnvironment() called at [/scripts/**init_script**.php:21]
> #15 init_phabricator_script() called at [/scripts/**init_script**.php:24]
> #16 require_once(string) called at [/scripts/sql/manage_storage.php:5]

### UPDATE:

**As of June 1st, 2021, Phabricator is no longer being maintained or updated.** [Click here for more info](https://admin.phacility.com/phame/post/view/11/phacility_is_winding_down_operations/).

Comment: [_Phabricator does not support PHP 7.0. Phabricator supports PHP 7.1 and newer._](https://secure.phabricator.com/T12101)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the php7 mysql extensions installed

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql`

Comment: We don't support php7 at this time (features are missing that will exist in 7.1)

Answer (score 2):

Phabricator does not support PHP7.0 (features are missing that exist in 7.1). Install a supported version of PHP like 5.6 or 7.1+, and yes make sure mysql extensions are there too.